When using remote VSCode, how can I activate conda envs, when not using Python?
I use VS Code to work remotely via SSH on a Linux HPC cluster. I don't have any admin rights, so I can't install anything system wide. I want to run and debug R and Perl code from VS Code. There is documentation on how to activate Conda envs from VS Code, but only when using Python, using the interpreter settings.
How do I activate a Conda env for using R, or one where I have installed Perl::LanguageServer for Perl?
